# Custom search from textbox switch/parameter

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I think I am over engineering this a bit. Any assistance is greatly appreciated on how I can fix this little problem. I have an app that searches multiple sites. But if a user types a custom parameter of g=, then it will search google. The problem is I have right now is it strips the G from the first word of my search term. For example, If I type g=golf game, google pops up with olf game. With the other searches, the = character is getting stripped. Should I use contains instead of this custom firstChars function?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter text to search on." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Need search term to search on.")
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
        Try
            'CHECK FOR GOOGLE.COM SEARCHING
            Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim MyChar() As Char = {"g", "G", "="}
            Dim NewString As String = MyString.TrimStart(MyChar)
            Dim myUri As New Uri("http://google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & NewString)
            Dim first2Chars As String
            Dim first3Chars As String
            Dim first4Chars As String
            first2Chars = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2)
            first3Chars = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 3)
            first4Chars = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 4)
            MsgBox(first2Chars)
            If first2Chars = "G=" Or first2Chars = "g=" Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myUri.AbsoluteUri)
            ElseIf first3Chars = "TS=" Or first3Chars = "ts=" Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://localhost/search.do?query=" & Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
            ElseIf first4Chars = "PIC=" Or first4Chars = "pic=" Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://localhost/search.do?query_pic=" & Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error running search. The error was: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: [`String.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yep. That sparked the fix. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Fixed doing this:
`If TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("G=") Or TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("g=") Then
                MyString = MyString.Remove(0, 2)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(MyString))
End If`